# Orbort Tor android

Tags: orbot

Does Orbot act as a firewall on android devices or any other devices it operates in and if not are there any plans to build a firewall by the organization that makes orbot?

By virtue of the fact that is has the ability to block and direct all incoming and outbound traffic through its VPN function which in turn only communicates with the entry tor nodes, a hacker would have to go through exit nodes relay nodes and then entry nodes to gain access to your device wich is virtually impossible with tor right?

Answer (score 1):

If you can redirect the internet traffic through orbot because your app let you do it, yes, you would practically use tor as a firewall (for that app obviously)